# MySQL parsing error in phpMyAdmin ("This type of clause was previously parsed")

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(tmp.mval), tmp.timekey FROM
(SELECT teghamas, 
        MAX(arzheq) as mval, 
        ceil(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(zhamanak)/(60 * 60)) AS timekey
   FROM `masnakcutyun`
   LEFT JOIN teghkentron ON `masnakcutyun`.`teghKentronId`=`teghkentron`.`teghKentronId` 
  WHERE teghkentron.hamaynq="London" group by timekey, teghkentron.teghamas)         
AS tmp
GROUP BY tmp.timekey
```

It works fine in phpMyAdmin. But there's a warning there saying:

"This type of clause was previously parsed (near select)".

Can you guess what is the problem? The query can execute and return the expected results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a phpMyAdmin parser bug, see [the issue on github](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12080), the query itself is valid.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL allow write subquery in `from` clause, but this is know [issue](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12080), you can create view and use it :

```
CREATE VIEW viewname AS (SELECT teghamas, 
    MAX(arzheq) as mval, 
    ceil(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(zhamanak)/(60 * 60)) AS timekey
    FROM `masnakcutyun`
    LEFT JOIN teghkentron ON `masnakcutyun`.`teghKentronId`=`teghkentron`.`teghKentronId` 
    WHERE teghkentron.hamaynq="London" group by timekey, teghkentron.teghamas) ;

SELECT SUM(mval) as MySum, timekey 
FROM viewname
GROUP BY timekey
```

Comment: It returns error: Unrecognized statement type. (near "with" at position 0)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same error message, in my case I just had few `UPDATE` clause without a semicolon to end.

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column`='val2' WHERE `id`=1 **;**
UPDATE `table` SET `column`='val2' WHERE `id`=2
```