# Trying to put a query inside another query in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to use a query as a data source from another query, but I keep getting a parsing error from SELECT. I am fairly new to SQL and phpmyadmin and not sure why this error is occurring. Heres my query that I am trying to do:

```
SELECT  CUS_CODE, 
 COUNT(LINE.INV_NUMBER) AS "Number of Invoices", 
 AVG("Invoice Total") AS "Average Invoice Amount", 
 MAX("Invoice Total") AS "Max Invoice Amount", 
 MIN("Invoice Total") AS "Min Invoice Amount", 
 Sum("Invoice Total") AS "Total Customer Purchases"
FROM    (SELECT CUS_CODE, LINE.INV_NUMBER AS INV_NUMBER,
        Sum(LINE.LINE_UNITS*LINE.LINE_PRICE) AS "Invoice Total"
        FROM    INVOICE, LINE 
        WHERE   INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER
        GROUP BY    CUS_CODE, LINE.INV_NUMBER)
GROUP BY    CUS_CODE;
```

Sorry if my question is not clear, but I can answer any questions to help clear it up.

Comment: The outer query has only access to the fields exposed by the derived table created by the subquery. It doesn't have access to the actual tables of the database, like, say, `LINE`.

Comment: Apart from that you *have to* give an alias to the derived table.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos How do I give an alias to the table before? I tried to find it but I couldn't find out how to give it an alias.

Comment: `... GROUP BY    CUS_CODE, LINE.INV_NUMBER) AS t ...`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos so I have to use AS for the inner query?

Comment: Yes, followed by the alias name, like, `as t`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I tried putting it as an alias, but I still get an error under the SELECT in the inner query, saying that the type of clause was previously parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Your query:

```
SELECT CUS_CODE,
    COUNT(LINE.INV_NUMBER) AS "Number of Invoices",
    AVG("Invoice Total") AS "Average Invoice Amount",
    MAX("Invoice Total") AS "Max Invoice Amount",
    MIN("Invoice Total") AS "Min Invoice Amount",
    Sum("Invoice Total") AS "Total Customer Purchases"
FROM (
    SELECT CUS_CODE,
        LINE.INV_NUMBER,
        Sum(LINE.LINE_UNITS * LINE.LINE_PRICE) AS "Invoice Total"
    FROM INVOICE,
        LINE
    WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER
    GROUP BY CUS_CODE, INV_NUMBER
    )
GROUP BY CUS_CODE;
```

A couple of problems here:

1. In your outer query you reference `LINE.INV_NUMBER` but the `LINE` table is not available in this context. It's the `INV_NUMBER` of your subquery that you want.
2. Your subquery lacks an alias so you have no way to refer to it in your outer query. This will just throw an error without the alias.

Fixed:

```
SELECT t1.CUS_CODE,
    COUNT(t1.INV_NUMBER) AS "Number of Invoices",
    AVG(t1."Invoice Total") AS "Average Invoice Amount",
    MAX(t1."Invoice Total") AS "Max Invoice Amount",
    MIN(t1."Invoice Total") AS "Min Invoice Amount",
    Sum(t1."Invoice Total") AS "Total Customer Purchases"
FROM (
    SELECT CUS_CODE,
        LINE.INV_NUMBER AS INV_NUMBER,
        Sum(LINE.LINE_UNITS * LINE.LINE_PRICE) AS "Invoice Total"
    FROM INVOICE,
        LINE
    WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = LINE.INV_NUMBER
    GROUP BY CUS_CODE,
        LINE.INV_NUMBER
    ) as t1
GROUP BY CUS_CODE;
```

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting an error for the SELECT, but I am also getting an error for the t1 alias.

Comment: Can you please share the error? I believe the syntax here is correct so it's something specific to your data that is causing the issue and the exact error message will help troubleshoot.

Comment: The "Previously parsed" warning message is from phpmyadmin and [is a known bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484077/mysql-parsing-error-in-phpmyadmin-this-type-of-clause-was-previously-parsed) The other error is probably the error from mysql and it is more pertinent.

Comment: It says a previous alias was found under the "t1"

Comment: OK. I can only assume that it was the superfluous field alias for the INV_NUMBER in the subquery. I have removed that.

Comment: Still getting the same error under the alias. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Am I able to use the query as a data source for another query? Instead of using an alias

Comment: Does the subquery run fine on it's own or does it throw an error?

Comment: It does run fine on its own.